# ReferenceError: require is not defined in Vue Component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

The following error occurs when I use screenfull.js(import screenfull from "screenfull") in a Vue component, what should I do, help me please.
[error info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/og5s7.png)

**version:**

vue: 2.6.14

@vue/cli-service: 5.0.4

babel-loader: 8.2.5

vue-loader: 17.0.0

webpack: 5.73.0

eslint: 7.32.0

**config:**

babel.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    '@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset'
  ],
  env: {
    development: {
      plugins: ['dynamic-import-node']
    }
  },
  plugins: ['lodash']
}
```

vue.config.js

```js
const {defineConfig} = require('@vue/cli-service')
const path = require('path')
const webpack = require('webpack')

function resolve(dir) {
  return path.join(__dirname, dir)
}

const name = process.env.VUE_APP_TITLE || 'hello'

module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: true,
  publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? '/' : '/',
  outputDir: 'dist',
  assetsDir: 'static',
  lintOnSave: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
  productionSourceMap: false,
  configureWebpack: {
    name: name,
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        '@': resolve('src')
      }
    },
    plugins: [
      new webpack.IgnorePlugin({
        resourceRegExp: /\.\/locale/,
        contextRegExp: /moment/
      })
    ]
  },
  chainWebpack(config) {
    config.plugins.delete('preload')
    config.plugins.delete('prefetch')

    // set svg-sprite-loader
    config.module
      .rule('svg')
      .exclude.add(resolve('src/assets/icons'))
      .end()
    config.module
      .rule('icons')
      .test(/\.svg$/)
      .include.add(resolve('src/assets/icons'))
      .end()
      .use('svg-sprite-loader')
      .loader('svg-sprite-loader')
      .options({
        symbolId: 'icon-[name]'
      })
      .end()

    config.when(process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'development', config => {
      config.optimization.splitChunks({
        chunks: 'all',
        cacheGroups: {
          libs: {
            name: 'chunk-libs',
            test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
            priority: 10,
            chunks: 'initial' 
          },
          elementUI: {
            chunks: 'all',
            name: 'chunk-elementUI', 
            priority: 20, 
            test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]_?element-ui(.*)/ 
          },
          commons: {
            chunks: 'all',
            name: 'chunk-commons',
            test: resolve('src/components'), 
            minChunks: 3,
            priority: 5,
            reuseExistingChunk: true
          },
          echarts: {
            chunks: 'all',
            test: /echarts/,
            name: 'echarts',
            enforce: true
          },
          lodash: {
            chunks: 'all',
            test: /lodash/,
            name: 'lodash',
            enforce: true
          },
          fabric: {
            chunks: 'all',
            test: /fabric/,
            name: 'fabric',
            enforce: true
          }
        }
      })
    })
  }
})
```

Comment: Click on the source lines in the stacktrace to see where the error comes from. If it's from the `screenfull` package - consider replacing it with something else or implementing the feature locally in your project source code.

Comment: Other packages also have this error, such as sheetjs. In fact, this question is strange. The project has just been created, with the default configuration, it works fine. But when I add some configuration items, this problem occurs. However, when I remove these configuration items, the problem still exists.

Comment: For Vue 2 - try with CLI-service 4 rather than 5.

Answer (score 0):

In `vue.config.js` you have `transpileDependencies` enabled, try to remove it or exclude the package:

```js
module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: false
})
```